# Getting extra quotes while sending nested JSON from AngularJS to Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I am trying to setup will_paginate gem in Rails and I want to get a nested object from AngularJS in order to display the requested items.

In AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.data = OutageLog.get({
  "pagination": {
    "page": 2
  }
});
```

I am using binding.pry to get the request's data and this is what I see:

```
{
"pagination"=>"{\"page\":2}",
 "format"=>"json",
 "controller"=>"api/v1/logs",
 "action"=>"index"
}
```

I want to get the pages value and I've tried everything such as `params[:pagination][:page]` to `JSON.parse params[:pagination].page` and everything fails because I need to have these extra quotes removed. How do I post a manageable JSON to Rails ?

EDIT: `JSON.parse params[:pagination])['page']` works but doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have you tried to pass an stringified JSON so you can parse it at the ROR end? something like `$scope.data = OutageLog.get(angular.toJson({
  "pagination": {
    "page": 2
  }
}));`

Comment: No I didn't, I tried with `JSON.stringify` but I was getting the same thing. Can you post a complete example please?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` and `angular.toJson` should have the same result in terms of quote escaping :(

Comment: I tried your example and now the pagination object does not exist at all inside the request.

Comment: You may want to use HashWithIndifferentAccess. See here:
 http://rubyquicktips.com/post/603292403/accessing-a-hash-with-either-string-or-symbol-keys